# I want to achieve row level locking using php in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, locking, innodb, using

I am designing this page where users will see the change orders for the day. I want only one person to edit one change order at a time. While other user can still edit other change order. The code i am pasting is for final page where the user is redirected after clicking on particular change order. Please help me by giving an example as i am very new to php and mysql. Thanks in advance.
`

```
<?php
$change = $_GET['value'];
mysqli_query('BEGIN');
$sql="SELECT  * FROM cat_firewall USE INDEX(id) WHERE chg_id='$change' FOR UPDATE";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

// Count table rows 
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>
---MORE CODE----
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
        <tr>
---MORE CODE----

<?php

$source_FW = $_POST['source_FW'];
$source_ACL =  $_POST['source_ACL'];
$destination_FW = $_POST['destination_FW'];
$destination_ACL =  $_POST['destination_ACL'];


if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){


foreach($source_FW as $key=>$value){
$sql1="UPDATE cat_firewall SET source_FW='$value' WHERE entry_id='$key' AND chg_id='$change' ";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
}
foreach($source_ACL as $key1=>$value1){
$sql2="UPDATE cat_firewall SET source_ACL='$value1' WHERE entry_id='$key1' AND chg_id='$change'  ";
mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
}
foreach($destination_FW as $key2=>$value2){
$sql3="UPDATE cat_firewall SET destination_FW='$value2' WHERE entry_id='$key2' AND chg_id='$change' ";
mysqli_query($con,$sql3);
}
foreach($destination_ACL as $key3=>$value3){
$sql4="UPDATE cat_firewall SET destination_ACL='$value3' WHERE entry_id='$key3' AND chg_id='$change'  ";
mysqli_query($con,$sql4);
}

echo "update complete";
}

sleep(120);
mysqli_query($con,'COMMIT');
?>'
```

`

Comment: @JayantRaizada there are a lot of issues you need to consider for this type of locking.  How do you determine the user is still viewing the order?  What if they leave their browser tab open for 24 hours?  What if they close the browser tab or their computer crashes while it's open without submitting a change?

Comment: If you want to lock it when the user goes to the edit page (before submitting the changes to make) ... then you could have a boolean field to toggle for the row. But you have to track as well if that user exits out of the edit page without submitting a change. Gets messy.

Comment: @Devon I am not looking for that thing right now but i have been reading about optimistic and pessimistic approach by creating different table and using that to store lock details. i was confused after reading that.

Comment: "if it's the same request, yes, but not if they want it locked when they view the page." true @Devon the CONNECTION_ID() needs to stay the same..

Comment: I want to lock it as soon as user clicks on the change order and gets to this page to edit rows and release the lock on the row once the submit button is clicked.

Comment: You need to implement pessimistic locking with PHP and SQL.. optimistic locking (MySQL innoDB read lock with FOR UPDATE) can't work because the PHP could get a new `CONNECTION_ID()` (invaliding the transaction state) between multiple webserver requests like @Devon pointed out..

Comment: @RickJames i choose to delete mine comments.. i didn't totally want to give a answer (because i wasn't sure the approach would work 100% because off the possible race conditions and other timing events) but some directions on how to do it.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks buddy your solution worked rickjames thanks for the explaination

Answer (score 0):

> I want to lock it as soon as user clicks on the change order and gets to this page to edit rows and release the lock on the row once the submit button is clicked.

That's a big red flag.  You should not expect InnoDB locking to run at the glacial speed of a human.

**Optmistic version:**

- Have a sequence number for the updates that happen.
- Grab that number at the *start* of the user looking at the values and scratching his head.
- Let the user (at glacial speed) make changes.
- Now send the updates *and the sequence number* back to the client API which does

The following:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT seq_num ... FOR UPDATE;
if the seq_num has changed, ROLLBACK this transaction and tell the user to start over.
else...
do the UPDATEs
update seq_num to a new number
COMMIT;
```

**Pessimistic approach...**

```
BEGIN;
SELECT who_is_editing FROM ... FOR UPDATE;
if someone else is editing, ROLLBACK and tell user to "try again later".
else...
UPDATE ... who_is_editing = $this_user;
COMMIT;
```

Now proceed to let the user do whatever he wants.  But, at the end, clear `who_is_editing`.

Caveat:  If a user simply vanishes, this 'lock' may never be released.  So...

- Have some job check for that.
- Warn the user that he has a limited amount of time to enter the changes.
- Verify *inside the UPDATE transaction* that the user still matches `who_is_editing`.  If not slap him around, telling him "you took too long!".

(Caveat: both of these approaches were hastily typed; please study carefully, looking for holes in the logic.)